# Synchronizing Exchange account on Mail Mac application

Tags: macos, mac, email, exchange

I'm trying to configure my Exchange mail account from work on my Mac. I configure the Mail app and I'm able to send email and receive emails, but some mails previous to configure it doesn't appear.. and on some it does it but I can't see the body of the mail. I'm not an expert, but,if I'm able to send emails and receive new ones the problem comes from the server?

By the way I'm using the same configuration on the iPad and works well.

Regards

Comment: Please add an answer to your own question with how you solved it then mark it as solved yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. The site's Q&A format relies on questions being just questions and answers being solutions to them.  Including an answer within the question makes what you're asking unclear, and others can't search for the answer.  Instead, please post the answer as an answer (read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this same issue by opening mail > click inbox folder > click Mailbox at top of screen > click "rebuild" at bottom of the dropdown list.  This should rebuild the entire Inbox and sub-folders tree.  It takes a while depending on the size of your exchange mailbox, but worked fine for me.  You can view progress by going to > window menu at top of screen > click "activity" and watch the folders rebuild their data...